# Struggling to ingest XML elements into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

xml and pandas.

What I am trying to do is learn Pandas dataframes, so I can work with and analyse data  coming from xml format. In particular I want to be confident in ingesting nested xml. In most of the tutorials I have read or seen on Youtube the instructions use flat XML documents with no nesting. This does not represent real world data so I am trying something a bit more challenging.

I have knocked up some code in python with a view to generating Pandas data-frames I can start practising querying the data with the Pandas framework.

I am using an open source music resource 'Discogs' because they provide access to large xmls with lots of data I can play with.

There are a couple of challenges with the source data, first being there is no standardised schema for the tables, so the structure of the data is not consistent throughout an XML table (an issue I feel mimics real data I'll eventually be working with for real).  The second is that the source files are huge the smallest being 1.5GB.

The first step I took was to split the files into smaller 200MB chunks. I then looked at the structure with a text editor so I had a good understanding of the tags and elements I needed to work with.  Right now I am working with a table called 'Masters'. I m hard coding he elements I am trying to pull into a dataframe to keep the exercise simple and contained for now.

I am using xml.etree to parse an xml document and interact with each element that contains.

I have created a static data-frame with 8 columns for data go into. Again keeping it simple for now.

I am then searching for specific elements within the parsed xml data and extracting the Text from each into a variable per element of interest.

The data is broken down within this xml as a set of rows, each wrapped in a tag called master. So I use this tag as my root anchor to loop around.

If I run the above as a print to console, all works fine up to this point, and I get a stream of nicely flattened and well formed data (excluding some elements which randomly have None values and therefore throw an error)

The last step was to then parse the strings from each collected element into a row appended to the data-frame.

This is where I hit a problem. The code to append to the data-frame seems straightforward, but when I add it to my for loop, I get an endless loop which I have to force to end.

I am obviously missing something here. advise greatly appreciated. Code I am working with below:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
    import re
    import pandas as pd
    tree = et.parse 
    ('/media/linux/Data1/TestData/masters/200mb/masters-01.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    masters_df_cols = ["MasterID", "MainRelese", "Title", "Year", 
    "Genre", "ArtistID", "ArtistName"]
     masters_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = masters_df_cols)

    for elem in root.iter('master'):
        if elem is not None:
            masterID = str(elem.get('id'))
            mainRelease = str(elem.find('main_release').text)
            year = str(elem.find('year').text)
            title = str(elem.find('title').text)
            genre = str(elem.find('./genres/genre').text)
            #style = str(elem.find('./styles/style').text)
            artistID = str(elem.find('./artists/artist/id').text)
            artistName = 
            str(elem.find('./artists/artist/name').text)
         print(masterID, ':', mainRelease, ':', year, ':', title, 
            ':', genre, ':', artistID, ':', artistName)
         masters_df = masters_df.append(pd.DataFrame([masterID, 
         mainRelease, year, title, genre, artistID, artistName], 
         index = masters_df_cols), ignore_index = True)

    print("Dataframe exported.")
```

The goal is to eventually take this exercise a replicate the knowledge I gain from it across different types of XMl, giving me the skill to searching dynamically through XMls for the tags and elements I want to draw out into a data-frame. Then use the data frames to generate meaningful stats about the data content. For now I am just trying to create simple flat data frames, with hard coded element values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A good [mcve] will show the input data and the expected output data and the error that occurred.  You've done a great job providing the code, but it cannot be run without at least some of the input data.

Comment: Thanks Rich, here is a smaller 20Mb chunk of the same data I am attempting to parse. <a href="https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/793072/masters-01.xml">masters-01.xml</a>  Kind regards  Duncan

Comment: The filehosting.org link does not work.

Comment: ok sorry about that I uploaded it again, not sure why the first one did not work? <a href="https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/793673/masters-01.xml">master-01.xml</a> tested this upload and the file is definitely there.

Comment: hhhhmm actually I think stack overflow is doing something to the link. I tried the download from here and your right an error is thrown, https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/793673/masters-01.xml trying without the suggested a tags

Comment: Yep that works, it was how I was loading the link to the comment, I followed a comment on another thread that said you needed to add in specific A tags, and those appear to have altered the link away from what works. a simple cut and paste of the actual url syntax into the comment field seems to have resolved that issue.

Comment: You need to include the data in the question.  Filehosting is asking for an email address to access the file.  Why can't you place the set of data that is giving the  problem in the context of your question? Please read [mcve].

Comment: Rich because what I am trying to parse is XML, my attempts to add a snippet of code to the above explanation does not work, StackOveiw interacts with the code itself and changes the raw data to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in the above code.

First and foremost, it is important to be vigilant with the whitespace and indentation in Python.  The copy/paste of the above code had a combination of space and tab whitespace.

The primary semantic problem is that `Pandas` is not good at incrementally building `DataFrames`.  Typically, the `Pandas` API is used to pass in an entire data structure at once to let the framework do its heavy lifting.  But of course there are methods to `append` `DataFrames`.  But here, a `DataFrame` was instantiated, and then for each iteration of the XML, a new `DataFrame` as instantiated and then appended to the first.  This is most certainly not what was desired and would cause memory headaches, especially in face of the voluminous XML which will require lots of host computer memory.

Then there were minor issues on constructing the row level `DataFrame`.  Here is a working MCVE illustrating how to make parsing discogs XML work including sample in-line data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import re
import pandas as pd
parser = et.XMLParser()
discogs_masters = """<masters>
<master id="18500"><main_release>155102</main_release><images><image height="588" type="primary" uri="" uri150="" width="600" /></images><artists><artist><id>212070</id><name>Samuel L Session</name><anv>Samuel L</anv><join /><role /><tracks /></artist></artists><genres><genre>Electronic</genre></genres><styles><style>Techno</style></styles><year>2001</year><title>New Soil</title><data_quality>Correct</data_quality><videos><video duration="489" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f05Ai921itM"><title>Samuel L - Velvet</title><description>Samuel L - Velvet</description></video><video duration="292" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOQsBOJLbwg"><title>Samuel L. - Danshes D'afrique</title><description>Samuel L. - Danshes D'afrique</description></video><video duration="348" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v23rSPG_StA"><title>Samuel L - Danses D'Afrique</title><description>Samuel L - Danses D'Afrique</description></video><video duration="288" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHo82ha6p40"><title>Samuel L - Body N' Soul</title><description>Samuel L - Body N' Soul</description></video><video duration="331" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDcqzHca5dk"><title>Samuel L - Into The Groove</title><description>Samuel L - Into The Groove</description></video><video duration="334" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DIYjJFl8Dk"><title>Samuel L - Soul Syndrome</title><description>Samuel L - Soul Syndrome</description></video><video duration="325" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o8yZMPqvNg"><title>Samuel L - Lush</title><description>Samuel L - Lush</description></video><video duration="346" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPwwJSc_-30"><title>Samuel L - Velvet ( Direct Me )</title><description>Samuel L - Velvet ( Direct Me )</description></video></videos></master>
<master id="18512"><main_release>33699</main_release><images><image height="150" type="primary" uri="" uri150="" width="150" /><image height="592" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600" /><image height="592" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600" /></images><artists><artist><id>212070</id><name>Samuel L Session</name><anv /><join /><role /><tracks /></artist></artists><genres><genre>Electronic</genre></genres><styles><style>Tribal</style><style>Techno</style></styles><year>2002</year><title>Psyche EP</title><data_quality>Correct</data_quality><videos><video duration="376" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_AfLqTdncI"><title>Samuel L. Session - Psyche Part 1</title><description>Samuel L. Session - Psyche Part 1</description></video><video duration="419" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nxvR8Zl9wY"><title>Samuel L. Session - Psyche Part 2</title><description>Samuel L. Session - Psyche Part 2</description></video><video duration="118" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYf4j0Pd2FU"><title>Samuel L. Session - Arrival</title><description>Samuel L. Session - Arrival</description></video></videos></master>
</masters>
"""
parser.feed(discogs_masters)
root = parser.close()

masters_df_cols = ["MasterID", "MainRelese", "Title", "Year", 
"Genre", "ArtistID", "ArtistName"]
masters_rows = []

for elem in root.iter('master'):
    if elem is not None:
        masterID = str(elem.get('id'))
        mainRelease = str(elem.find('main_release').text)
        year = str(elem.find('year').text)
        title = str(elem.find('title').text)
        genre = str(elem.find('./genres/genre').text)
        artistID = str(elem.find('./artists/artist/id').text)
        artistName = str(elem.find('./artists/artist/name').text)
    masters_rows.append([masterID, mainRelease, year, title, genre, artistID, artistName])

masters_df = pd.DataFrame(masters_rows, columns = masters_df_cols)
print(masters_df)
```

Produces this output

```
  MasterID MainRelese Title       Year       Genre ArtistID        ArtistName
0    18500     155102  2001   New Soil  Electronic   212070  Samuel L Session
1    18512      33699  2002  Psyche EP  Electronic   212070  Samuel L Session
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. Yes I am aware I keep messing up the white spaces. As I get more practice under my belt I hope to resolve that issue.  Thank-you also for explaining the Pandas issue, it helped me greatly. Kind regards Duncan